# How do I add a class to a div in HTML using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I want to use jQuery to add a class named `container-c-ml` to my HTML code. I have the following code below:

```
<div id="container">
<button>This is a button</button>
</div>
```

I have my HTML doc linked to a JavaScript file and I have jQuery added via the `<head>` tag of my doc. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").addClass("container-c-ml");
});
```

Good luck with further learning to code!